# How do I change the path name to fix my javac: invalid flag: error?

Tags: macos, java, atom-editor

I am using *atom.io* which works perfectly with my Python programs, but I can't run any Java without getting this error? From looking at other users questions on the issue, the answers said to change the path name but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
javac: invalid flag: /Users/MacBookHAL/Documents/AtomWorkspace/CompSci/Test
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: How are you running the command? Are you running it through terminal?

Comment: I am just trying to run a simple program in the atom.io IDE but I get the error when I run it.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file/running a file without spaces in the name? How do you know the spaces are the issue?

Comment: I don't, but I don't know how to edit the path name. I have looked at previous Stack questions on this issue and they all have said it is a problem with the path name.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question to include that information.

Comment: Regarding the path name, what file are you trying to run? Or is it all java files that will do that?

Comment: Yes all java projects that I am trying to run are all giving me this error.

Comment: Did you configure atom at all for java? For example installing a plugin/package?

Comment: I installed linter packages for Java specifically and updated Java but not much else, anything I should have done?

Comment: What packages specifically?
Also, what is the output in terminal.app of `which javac`?

Comment: Can you try to isolate the issue to atom by running in terminal `javac <your-.java-file>`?

Comment: When I run `javac` followed by my file name in the terminal I am given the same error message.

Comment: Ah, that's important. You should edit your question with that information. What's the output of `which javac`?

Comment: when I run `which javac` it returns `/usr/bin/javac`

Comment: Did you put quotes around your file name when running `javac`?

Comment: Do you have the [script](https://atom.io/packages/script) package installed?